# Is there a way to test a link on a image with Symfony/Panther

Tags: image, hyperlink, functional-testing, symfony-panther

thx for helping me on this :)

Im developping a serie of test on a symfony app with Symfony/Panther. Im looking for a way to test if my logo redirect to the correct page. The way I see it, is I have to test the link and then click on it to test the redirection.
The panther documentation is quiet specific about link testing see here:

https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-symfony-panther-a-browser-testing-and-web-scraping-library-for-php

I also saw how to find an image via DomCrawler np with that...

SO what I have tried, is to adapt the link testing method to an image, of course it didnt work cause the image is not a string as expected by the method

So if someone have an idea how to test the redirection on a image link It ll be awesome. Thx in advance

```
<?php
namespace App\Tests;

 use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;  

 class assertLogoRedirectTo extends PantherTestCase   
{
    public function test()
    {
    
        $client = static::createPantherClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET','https://my.sibluconnect.com');        
    
        $client->waitFor('.login');        
        $image = $crawler->selectImage('siblu')->image(); 
        $link = $crawler->selectLink($image)->link();        
        $crawler = $client->click($link);       
   
    }
}
```

Running the test shows this error:

> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:12947/devtools/browser/d3a0e57f-2b00-4eb3-97e3-64986cf0495e
> E                                                                   1
> / 1 (100%)/test1//test2//test3//test4/
>
> Time: 11.17 seconds, Memory: 38.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. App\Tests\assertLogoIsvisible::test Object of class
>    Symfony\Component\Panther\DomCrawler\Image could not be converted to
>    string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit on my post...I found the way to do it.

A image is not a link, a link is a `<a href>` or `<button>` so the test shoudnt be looking for a image to be a link. So Ive try another method which is trying to target the link via its position in the page. As this link is my logo it is the first  `<a href>` on the page.

Here's the code Ive tried and it works just fine !!!

```
namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;  

class assertLogoRedirectTo extends PantherTestCase   // Success
{
public function test()
{

    echo'/test1/';
    $client = static::createPantherClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://my.sibluconnect.com/fr/');       

    $link = $crawler->filter('a')->eq(0)->attr('href');
    $crawler = $client->request('GET',$link);
    $this->assertSame('http://sibluconnect.com/', $client->getCurrentURL());


 }
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the futur ;)

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but it shows up in Google, so an alternative: if your image has an ID, then it appears that you can click it as follows:

```
$this->client->getMouse()->clickTo("#yourIDHere");
$crawler = $this->client->refreshCrawler();  // reload content
```